# Ajax Image Editor not working in Chrome

Tags: ajax, image, google-chrome, editor

I'm using the Open Source Ajax Image Editor from http://www.flash-image-editor.com/opensource,index

For a live testing from them http://www.flash-image-editor.com/ajax-image-editor/

It works fine in Firefox, Opera and IE. However, Chrome (v23.0.1271.64 m) seems to like to be special.

It only displays the edited images in the center after i click an image from the history window.

I attempted to force a re-display of the image. Did not work.

I looked for the cause of the 1 error and 1 warning:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'focus' of null
>
> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tried looking for what's causing them to no avail.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why Chrome will not display the image on its own?